# Check only specific rows of kendo grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

I'm using a kendo grid on a edit modal. When the modal pops up i need to check the specific rows. this my kendo grid.

```
    function LoadControllerGrid(list) {

        var ListofrowIds = list
        $("#controllerGrid1").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                type: "json",
                //    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("GetControllerList", "Account"))",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json"
                    },

                },
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "UserId",
                        fields: {
                            'Id': { type: "string" },
                            'Name': { type: "string" },
                            'Description': { type: "string" },
                            'URL': { type: "string" },
                        },

                    },
                    data: 'data',
                    total: 'TotalCount'
                },
                complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    //     HidePageLoader();

                },
                pageSize: 5,
                serverPaging: true,
                serverSorting: true,
                serverFiltering: true,
                columnMenu: true
            },
            height: 300,
            groupable: false,
            sortable: true,
            filterable: true,
            pageable: {
                refresh: true,
                pageSizes: 5000
            },
            columns: [{ template: '<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"  />', width: "35px" },
                      { field: "Description", title: "Actions" }, ]



        });
}
```

I pass the ids of specific rows that need to be checked to the function. kendo grid above display the all the rows.how can i check the check boxes of those particular rows.